I am getting error like"AnonymousUser" in django . when retrive data from database . based on logged user
this is views code
def view_transaction(request):
    print(request.user)
    user_transactions = Transactions.objects.filter(user_account = request.user)
    return render(request,'transactions.html',{'user_transactions':user_transactions})

is the above code correct or not, i think when it check whether user login is not present here.
models.py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=45,primary_key=True,blank=False,unique=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=45,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Transactions(models.Model):
    transaction_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_transaction = models.DateField()
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TRANSACTION_TYPES)
    transaction_medium = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TRANSACTION_MEDIUM)
    transaction_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)

when i login,it shows some details about customer.
I want transaction details but i didn't get any, instead i got error like anonymous user.

You aren't logged in when making that request which means request.user is an AnonymousUser object. You should require users to login before accessing that page.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Link to transactions page is only available when a user logged in. so i have already logged in.

You can add the @login_required decorator to your view_transaction view to validate whether the user is logged in or not

@Vikrant while adding login_required it shows error in urls Page not found (404)
